# Sending an array to servlet from jsp page and recieving it in servlet

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets

how to send an array to servlet from jsp page and recieving it in servlet?

When i receive an array in servlet end i am not getting any value.

My code:

```
var arrayJSP = new Array();
//filling some elements in  array

  $.get('ServletSave',{arrayServlet:arrayJSP} );
```

Servlet side:

```
String[] arrayServlet=request.getParameterValues("arrayServlet");
```

Please help with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use better, more descriptive, names, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needs to be an array

```
String[] arrayY = request.getParameterValues("arrayY");
```